# Cannot call constraintLayout.remove() from another thread;

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Lets say I have a `ImageView` that executes at a click of a `Button`:

```
 final ImageView ball = new ImageView(v.getContext());
 ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_1);
 gameConstraintLayout.addView(ball);
```

When I click that button, it first off makes the ball appears , creates and runs another thread that tell itself to sleep 1000 milliseconds `sleep(long millis)` then removes the ball by calling `ConstrainLayout.removeView(view)`

Here is the full minimal code:

```
        final ImageView ball = new ImageView(v.getContext());
        currentBullet.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_1);
        gameConstraintLayout.addView(ball);

        ballAppears.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final ImageView ball = new ImageView(v.getContext());
            currentBullet.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_1);
            gameConstraintLayout.addView(ball);

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                        contraintLayout.removeView(ball)
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            });


        }
    });
```

## Problem is;

The ball appears on screen, the other thread successfully sleeps for 1000 milliseconds, but, It crashes when It tries to remove the ball from the constraint layout in the other thread.

### Logcat:

```
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views**.

  at  android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.removeView(ConstraintLayout.java:645)
    at  com.mobilegames.***.******.GameActivity$1$1.run(GameActivity.java:51)
```

The code that causes the problem is:

```
gameConstraintLayout.removeView(ball_1);
```

AS it seems,I cant access the Constraint layout from the other thread but, I can still change the X and the Y of the ball.

**I even tried running that piece of code in the UI theard `runOnUIThread(...)`**, but to no avail.

Here is the runONUIThread code:

```
       shootTank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final ImageView currentBullet = new ImageView(v.getContext());
            currentBullet.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_model1);
            gameConstraintLayout.addView(currentBullet);

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            gameConstraintLayout.removeView(currentBullet);
                        }
                    });


                }
            };
            thread.start();

        }
    });
```

Any possible solutions? Keep in mind that I change the X and Y's of the ball after every second.

AND YES, I did check other Questions. The answer in those ones said to simply run it on the UI thread, but of course I already tried that. If i run the sleep(long millis) into the UI thread, obliviously, the whole app would be irresponsible.

*(This is not the full app; it was broken down into a much more simpler and understandable Question. I end up changing the ball's X and Y in the separate thread, but that inst what is causing the problem. Please tell me in comments if editing is necessary)*

***Sorry for small grammar mistakes***

Comment: Where do you exactly call `thread.start()` and how do you make use of `runOnUiThread()`? Include that code too.

Comment: You can't change UI from thread other then UI thread, you can use Async task

Comment: I dont know and never heard of Async; please post an answer

Comment: I would suggest you to make use of `Handler` and its `postDelayed()` method. There are tons of example available on internet on its usage.

Comment: @waqaslam I will take a look at it; I am a bit familiar with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use handler to perform your actions with some delay. For example:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       gameConstraintLayout.removeView(currentBullet);
   }
}, 1000);  // here 1000 is delay in milliseconds (1sec)
```

Comment: Weirdly, this acually worked; Can you answer one more question? How come Thread didint work but Handler did?

Comment: Nothing's weird about `Handler`. If you are working with threads and schedulers then Handler is a very useful and perfect tool available in Android.

Comment: I didint mean using Handler is weird, its just that they are very similar for me and do the same thing. I guess Handler > Thread

Comment: Previously you were trying to make the edit on a worker thread/ background thread, which was not possible (the error you were getting), what the Handler does it when your main thread (the one that can make changes to the UI) finishes all its work, it’s begins any “post” or “postDelayed” callbacks, so instead of running the piece of code on a worker thread, it’s now waiting until your mainThread is free and then making the changes on the main thread, for more information have a look into MainThread/UI thread and Worker/Background Threads